# "oil reserves" VS "oil reserve"

Tags: singular-vs-plural, nouns

> The Persian Gulf has 65 percent of the world's oil reserves.

Is it because there are many reserves on earth that the plural form of reserve is used?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you usually  speak of *reserves*, such as gold, copper, oil, etc.

***[Reserves:](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/reserves.html)***

> 4. Energy industries: Computed or estimated quantity of hydrocarbons or minerals that can be extracted from known fields at an economical cost.

(businessdictionary.com)

> ***Oil reserves denote the amount of crude oil that can be technically recovered at a cost that is financially feasible*** at the present price of oil. Hence reserves will change with the price, ***unlike oil resources, which include all oil that can be technically recovered at any price.*** Reserves may be for a well, for a reservoir, for a field, for a nation, or for the world. Different classifications of reserves are related to their degree of certainty.

[image]

(Wikipedia)

Answer (score 0):

It's not how many reserves there are, it's how much reserves there are.

Many reserves would mean reserves located at many distinct places. That's not how the word reserves is used.

"Much" refers to quantity of oil. 65% of the world's oil reserves means 65% of the known quantity of oil.

Comment: I applaud you explanation but not **how much reserves** even as a play or words!